# Glossaries 'unknown option' Error

Tags: glossaries

In the following, I create a separate glossary that I do not want to have hyperlinked (in my actual document, the glossary without links will not be displayed).

The following MWE generates an error:

> Unknown option 'nohypertypes' for package 'glossaries'

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nohypertypes={common}]{glossaries}

\newglossary{common}{cacr}{cacn}{Common Acronyms}
\newglossaryentry{unlinkedtest}{
    type={common},
    name={test glossary entry},
    description={should not be linked}}
\newglossaryentry{linkedtest}{
    name={test glossary entry},
    description={should be linked}}
\makeglossaries%

\begin{document}
    This should be linked: \gls{linkedtest}\par%
    This should not be linked: \gls{unlinkedtest}
    \printglossary[type=common]%
    \printglossary[type=main]%
\end{document}
```

The `nohypertypes` option is detailed as a new change in v3.04 and the log file shows `glossaries` v3.04 is being loaded. Without the `nohypertypes` option, the MWE works, except that both `\gls` are linked to their glossary entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&category=glossaries&status=All&search_string=&key=17) of `glossaries` 3.04. It has been fixed in version 3.05. Please update that package.

Comment: How can I update it? In TeX Live Utility, I don't get the option to update anything - do I have to get MacTeX 2013?

Comment: @Chris This depends on your system and distribution, I think [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/21591) should help.

Comment: So if I want to use the TeX Live Utility to manage the packages installed, it has to be the most up to date version, which is why my 2012 version no longer lists any available updates. 2013 update looks the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

At least with 3.05 (I'm using TeX Live 2013) the option is 'nohypertypes' rather than 'nohyperlist'.

Good Luck,
Herb Schulz

Comment: Oops copy/paste error in my MWE